# Neo4JClient 3.1 to 5.1 update query that match two nodes and create relationship

Tags: neo4jclient

I am struggling to update my code that uses Neo4JClient v3.x to work with the latest Neo4J server and Neo4jClient v5.x.

my query basically will create 2 nodes and a relationship between them.
if any node or both nodes does not exist, they will be created along the relationship

old working query:

```cs
query1 = client.Cypher
    .Match("(e1:Entity)", "(e2:Entity)")
    .Where("e1.Id={id1} and e2.Id={id2}")
    .WithParam("id1", id1)
    .WithParam("id2", id2)
    .WithParam("line", line)
    .Merge("(e1)-[r:REF {LINE:{line}}]->(e2)");
```

above code does not work in the new version of Neo4j server / Neo4jClient
my attempt to modify it currently create duplicate nodes instead of unique ones

```cs
query1 = client.Cypher
    .Create("(e1:Entity $id1)")
    .Create("(e2:Entity $id2)")
    .WithParam("id1",new { Id = id1 })
    .WithParam("id2", new { Id = id2 })
    .WithParam("line", line)
    .Create("(e1)-[r:REF {LINE:$line}\]->(e2)");
```

can you help me convert the first query above to work in the newer version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query does a `MATCH` at the beginning, which would never have `CREATE`d `e1` or `e2` - you would need to use `MERGE` to achieve what you're after.

This query:

```cs
query1 = client.Cypher
    .Merge("(e1:Entity {Id: $id1})")
    .Merge("(e2:Entity {Id: $id2})")
    .Merge("(e1)-[r:REF {LINE:$line}]->(e2)")
    .WithParams(new { id1, id2, line });
```

should do what you actually want.

`e1` and `e2` would be `CREATE`d *if* they are not in the database, or `MATCH`ed if they *are* in the database.

> You might want to consider if you want the relationship done in the same way, in which case, swap `.Create(...)` to be `.Merge(...)`

EDIT: I noticed in your original query that you did in fact `MERGE` the relationship, so I've updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added the missing ")" in Merge() calls in your code and tested it. it seems to be working just like the code I have and it still creates duplicate nodes . I think the issue is that each node has two properties the default Id "<id>" and the "Id" I am passing that is why duplicates are being created now . so I am trying to figure out how to set the Id now.

Comment: `Merge` requires a unique property - in this case `Id` - the `<id>` you are referring to is the internal node id and should not be used. I've used `Id` as that is what your original statement did (though I have just noticed you did `Merge` the relationship, so I have updated my code to reflect that). You don't have to use `Id`, for instance, on a Person `Email` might be the unique property.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. your query is correct . with first test It still created duplicate nodes but then I figured that actual issue was the async call to execute the query. my test data will cause two quires to be executed with one common node. after adding .Wait() method duplication issue is resolved.